# pymc3 Heaviside step function

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc3

In pymc3, how can the Heaviside step function be applied as a deterministic transform?

Any step function will work, but I'm asking about the Heaviside step function specifically to disambiguate it from what the documentation refers to as a "step function", which is talking about *sampling* steps, which are irrelevant to what I'm looking for and makes finding relevant documentation difficult to locate, if it exists. Also I wasn't able to find somewhere that all supported transforms are documented.

I want `1 if x >= 0 else 0`, but writing it literally like that won't work because presumably `x >= 0` evaluates to an object, and so the `if` expression will immediately evaluate to 1, and then `h` will always be 1.

```
import pymc3 as pm

with pm.Model() as model:
    x = pm.Normal('x', mu=0, sigma=1)
    h = pm.Deterministic('h', 1 if x >= 0 else 0)  # ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`theano.tensor.switch`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#theano.tensor.switch). That is,

```
import pymc3 as pm
import theano.tensor as tt

with pm.Model() as model:
    x = pm.Normal('x', mu=0, sigma=1)
    h = pm.Deterministic('h', tt.switch(x < 0, 0, 1))
```